# Error in angularjs minification in mvc5

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

I have written long angularjs application without testing minification. But when i testing with minification i getting error in  below code can any one help in fixing tis. can any one explain me how i need to implement the DI in below code. I am using these service for other contollers

```
angular.module('app').controller(controllerId, ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$window', main]);
    function main($rootScope, $scope, $window) {
};
```

Here's the error message:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/nomod?p0=app. scripts:1
>   Error: [ng:areq]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/ng/areq?p0=crudJobCtrl&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
>   at Error (native)

Thanks in Advance
Jai

Comment: ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$window',, main]   using double ,,

Answer (score 0):

create controller like this:

```
angular.module("app", []);
angular.module("app").controller("controllerName", ["$rootScope", "$scope", "$window",
    function($rootScope, $scope, $window) {

    }
]);
```